# How to set the measurement matrix of opencv kalman filter depending on the measurement dimensions [OpenCV+Python]

Tags: python, opencv, kalman-filter

I am working on a tracking application where I use the opencv kalman filter to validate my current measurement of the position. I use the code from [this](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/51327/how-to-find-the-probability-of-kalman-filter-states-opencvpython?newreg=4ed7323f17cc478ab17edd9c28b4a229) question:
At first I calculate velocity (v) and accelearation (a) of my moving object at (x, y). These 4 values are used as my kalman state. I initiate the kalman filter as follows:
(`np.eye(n,m)` generates the identity matrix with dimensions nxm):

```py
def initKalman(init_state, fps):
    kalman = cv.KalmanFilter(4, 4, 2)
    kalman.transitionMatrix = np.array([[1., 0., 1/fps, 0.],
                                        [0., 1., 0., 1/fps],
                                        [0., 0., 1., 0.],
                                        [0, 0., 0., 1.]])

    kalman.measurementMatrix = 1. * np.eye(2, 4)
    kalman.measurementNoiseCov = 1e-3 * np.eye(2, 2)
    kalman.processNoiseCov = 1e-5 * np.eye(4, 4) 
    kalman.errorCovPost = 1e-1 * np.eye(4, 4)
    kalman.statePost = init_state.reshape(4, 1)

    return kalman


kinematics = np.array((velocity, acceleration), dtype=np.float32)
kalman_state = np.concatenate((point, kinematics))
kalman_filter = initKalman(kalman_state, fps = 15)
```

During operation the correction is done as follows:

```py
def correct_kalman(kalman, state):
    measurement = (np.dot(kalman.measurementNoiseCov, np.random.randn(2, 1))).reshape(-1)
    measurement = np.dot(kalman.measurementMatrix, state) + measurement
    return kalman.correct(measurement)

kinematics = np.array((velocity, acceleration), dtype=np.float32)
kalman_state = np.concatenate((point, kinematics))
correct_kalman(kalman_filter, kalman_state)
```

It seems to work witch is great, but im trying to understand why. In my understanding it shouldn't work because in `correct_kalman()` the velocity and acceleration are ommited in this code line:
`measurement = np.dot(kalman.measurementMatrix, state) + measurement`
because the measurementmatrix is just 2 x 4. (In fact, if I set acceleration and speed to 0, the behavior of the filter does not change.)
For Example take the `kalman_state = np.array([10., 20., 25., 75.])` and calculate the dot product with the `measurementMatrix = 1. * np.eye(2, 4)`
then `measurement = np.dot(kalman.measurementMatrix, kalman_state)` is just

> `>>> measurement`
>   `array([10., 20.])`

v and a are gone.
So I changed my measurementMatrix and my measurementNoiseCov to `4 x 4` dimensionality and adjusted my correction acordingly by using `np.random.randn(4, 1)` but now the kalman filter is way to sluggish and falls behind the measurement.

Why is the first approach working if v and a are not used?
How can I change the measurement matrix in a more targeted way than just iteratively adjusting the values?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Maybe I have to calculate the x and y velocities independently?

Comment: Have you considered the possibility of using a correlation tracker by dlib? it is more robust than kalman